# Heatmap with ggplot2, produced by two similar datasets

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to produce a calendar heatmap plot, using ggplot2, a package I have only recently started working with. Most of my code is taken by these posts [1](http://www.r-bloggers.com/ggplot2-time-series-heatmaps/) , [2](http://www.ivankuznetsov.com/2012/04/heatmap-visualization-of-sick-day-trends-in-finland-with-r-ggplot2-and-google-correlate.html). Unlike those two examples, my data lacks continuous dates so I proceeded to write first a dataset with dates ranging the whole period I am interested in ( from 01/01/2015 to 31/07/2015), plotting this dataset and then using it as a base for the actual data.  My code follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(zoo)

res<- structure(list(mydates = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 10L, 12L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 38L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 
53L, 54L, 58L, 60L, 61L, 71L, 76L, 78L, 89L, 90L, 92L, 93L, 95L, 
96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 102L, 103L, 107L, 112L, 113L, 115L, 
116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 
127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L), .Label = c("2015-02-16 00:00:00", 
"2015-02-17 00:00:00", "2015-02-18 00:00:00", "2015-02-19 00:00:00", 
"2015-02-20 00:00:00", "2015-02-21 00:00:00", "2015-02-22 00:00:00", 
"2015-02-23 00:00:00", "2015-02-24 00:00:00", "2015-02-25 00:00:00", 
"2015-02-26 00:00:00", "2015-02-27 00:00:00", "2015-02-28 00:00:00", 
"2015-03-01 00:00:00", "2015-03-02 00:00:00", "2015-03-03 00:00:00", 
"2015-03-04 00:00:00", "2015-03-05 00:00:00", "2015-03-06 00:00:00", 
"2015-03-07 00:00:00", "2015-03-08 00:00:00", "2015-03-09 00:00:00", 
"2015-03-10 00:00:00", "2015-03-11 00:00:00", "2015-03-12 00:00:00", 
"2015-03-13 00:00:00", "2015-03-14 00:00:00", "2015-03-15 00:00:00", 
"2015-03-16 00:00:00", "2015-03-17 00:00:00", "2015-03-18 00:00:00", 
"2015-03-19 00:00:00", "2015-03-20 00:00:00", "2015-03-21 00:00:00", 
"2015-03-22 00:00:00", "2015-03-23 00:00:00", "2015-03-24 00:00:00", 
"2015-03-25 00:00:00", "2015-03-26 00:00:00", "2015-03-27 00:00:00", 
"2015-03-28 00:00:00", "2015-03-29 00:00:00", "2015-03-30 01:00:00", 
"2015-03-31 01:00:00", "2015-04-01 01:00:00", "2015-04-02 01:00:00", 
"2015-04-03 01:00:00", "2015-04-04 01:00:00", "2015-04-05 01:00:00", 
"2015-04-06 01:00:00", "2015-04-07 01:00:00", "2015-04-08 01:00:00", 
"2015-04-09 01:00:00", "2015-04-10 01:00:00", "2015-04-11 01:00:00", 
"2015-04-12 01:00:00", "2015-04-13 01:00:00", "2015-04-14 01:00:00", 
"2015-04-15 01:00:00", "2015-04-16 01:00:00", "2015-04-17 01:00:00", 
"2015-04-18 01:00:00", "2015-04-19 01:00:00", "2015-04-20 01:00:00", 
"2015-04-21 01:00:00", "2015-04-22 01:00:00", "2015-04-23 01:00:00", 
"2015-04-24 01:00:00", "2015-04-25 01:00:00", "2015-04-26 01:00:00", 
"2015-04-27 01:00:00", "2015-04-28 01:00:00", "2015-04-29 01:00:00", 
"2015-04-30 01:00:00", "2015-05-01 01:00:00", "2015-05-02 01:00:00", 
"2015-05-03 01:00:00", "2015-05-04 01:00:00", "2015-05-05 01:00:00", 
"2015-05-06 01:00:00", "2015-05-07 01:00:00", "2015-05-08 01:00:00", 
"2015-05-09 01:00:00", "2015-05-10 01:00:00", "2015-05-11 01:00:00", 
"2015-05-12 01:00:00", "2015-05-13 01:00:00", "2015-05-14 01:00:00", 
"2015-05-15 01:00:00", "2015-05-16 01:00:00", "2015-05-17 01:00:00", 
"2015-05-18 01:00:00", "2015-05-19 01:00:00", "2015-05-20 01:00:00", 
"2015-05-21 01:00:00", "2015-05-22 01:00:00", "2015-05-23 01:00:00", 
"2015-05-24 01:00:00", "2015-05-25 01:00:00", "2015-05-26 01:00:00", 
"2015-05-27 01:00:00", "2015-05-28 01:00:00", "2015-05-29 01:00:00", 
"2015-05-30 01:00:00", "2015-05-31 01:00:00", "2015-06-01 01:00:00", 
"2015-06-02 01:00:00", "2015-06-03 01:00:00", "2015-06-04 01:00:00", 
"2015-06-05 01:00:00", "2015-06-06 01:00:00", "2015-06-07 01:00:00", 
"2015-06-08 01:00:00", "2015-06-09 01:00:00", "2015-06-10 01:00:00", 
"2015-06-11 01:00:00", "2015-06-12 01:00:00", "2015-06-13 01:00:00", 
"2015-06-14 01:00:00", "2015-06-15 01:00:00", "2015-06-16 01:00:00", 
"2015-06-17 01:00:00", "2015-06-18 01:00:00", "2015-06-19 01:00:00", 
"2015-06-20 01:00:00", "2015-06-21 01:00:00", "2015-06-22 01:00:00", 
"2015-06-23 01:00:00", "2015-06-24 01:00:00", "2015-06-25 01:00:00", 
"2015-06-26 01:00:00", "2015-06-27 01:00:00", "2015-06-28 01:00:00", 
"2015-06-29 01:00:00", "2015-06-30 01:00:00"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(0.853658536585366, 0.666666666666667, 0.642857142857143, 
    0.88, 0.988888888888889, 0.957746478873239, 0.5, 0.75, 0.565217391304348, 
    0.714285714285714, 1, 0.7, 0.8, 0.75, 0.8, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.931034482758621, 1, 0.740740740740741, 1, 0.714285714285714, 
    0.666666666666667, 0.952380952380952, 0.625, 0.571428571428571, 
    0.75, 0.80952380952381, 0.941176470588235, 1, 0.833333333333333, 
    0.818181818181818, 0.5, 0.818181818181818, 0.714285714285714, 
    0.727272727272727, 0.9375, 1, 0.994736842105263, 1, 0.709677419354839, 
    0.0440251572327044, 0.0307692307692308, 0.247933884297521, 
    0.75, 1, 0.857142857142857, 0.666666666666667, 0.857142857142857, 
    0.109243697478992, 1, 0.571428571428571, 1, 0.6, 0.75, 0.5625, 
    0.8, 0.625, 0.555555555555556, 1, 0.818181818181818, 0.857142857142857, 
    1, 1, 0.75, 0.571428571428571, 0.5, 0.769230769230769, 

    0.857142857142857, 
        0.777777777777778, 0.8, 1, 0.866666666666667, 1, 0.75, 0.888888888888889, 
        0.5)), .Names = c("mydates", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -76L), class = "data.frame")

    sd1<-as.Date("2015-01-01")
    sd2<-as.Date("2015-07-31")
    mydates<-seq.Date(sd1,sd2,"day")
    dat<-as.data.frame(mydates)
    colnames(dat)[1]<-c("date")
    dat$year<-as.numeric(as.POSIXlt(dat$date)$year+1900)
    dat$month<-as.numeric(as.POSIXlt(dat$date)$mon+1)
    dat$monthf<-factor(dat$month,levels=as.character(1:12),labels=c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"),ordered=TRUE)
    dat$weekday = as.numeric(format(as.POSIXlt(dat$date),"%u"))
    dat$weekdayf<-factor(dat$weekday,levels=(1:7),labels=(c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun")),ordered=TRUE)
    dat$yearmonth<-as.yearmon(dat$date)
    dat$yearmonthf<-factor(dat$yearmonth)
    dat$week <- as.numeric(format(as.POSIXlt(dat$date),"%W"))
    dat<-ddply(dat,.(yearmonthf),transform,monthweek=1+week-min(week))
    dat$value <-rep(0,nrow(dat))

    res$year<-as.numeric(as.POSIXlt(res$mydates)$year+1900)
    res$month<-as.numeric(as.POSIXlt(res$mydates)$mon+1)
    res$monthf<-factor(res$month,levels=as.character(1:12),labels=c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"),ordered=TRUE)
    res$weekday <- as.numeric(format(as.POSIXlt(res$mydates),"%u"))
    res$weekdayf<-factor(res$weekday,levels=(1:7),labels=(c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun")),ordered=TRUE)
    res$yearmonth<-as.yearmon(res$mydates)
    res$yearmonthf<-factor(res$yearmonth)
    res$week <- as.numeric(format(as.POSIXlt(res$mydates),"%W"))
    res<-ddply(res,.(yearmonthf),transform,monthweek=1+week-min(week))

    plot1<- ggplot(dat, aes(weekdayf,monthweek,fill=value))+ scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="blue") + 
      geom_tile(colour = "black") + facet_grid(monthf~.) +
      xlab("Day") + ylab("Week of the month")+ theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
                                                     panel.grid.major=element_blank()) 
    plot1 <- plot1 + scale_y_reverse()
    plot2 <- plot1 + geom_tile(data=res,colour="black")
```

The plotting of the "helper" dataset goes on as expected,
but once I try to plot the second dataset, everything gets whacked up: tiles of the heatmap get displaced, random(?) tiles get left blank etc. Where do I go wrong?

**plot1:**
[image]

**plot2:**
[image]

**Edit:** Problem is most probably caused by
    res<-ddply(res,.(yearmonthf),transform,monthweek=1+week-min(week))
Which is wrong in any case.

Comment: @RHertel could you also please add the plot produced by  plot1+ scale_y_reverse()

Comment: @RHertel The code has two plots produced by lines:1)plot1+ scale_y_reverse()
2)plot1+ scale_y_reverse()+geom_tile(data=res,colour="black") . You added the 2nd one and btw thank you for that :)

Comment: @RHertel that would be perfect, thank you :)

Comment: @RHertel it is exactly as it should be

Comment: Good. Glad I could help. Not sure I can solve your problem, though.

Comment: What were you expecting? Load `dplyr` and do `res %>% arrange(monthf, monthweek, weekday)  %>%  select(monthf, monthweek, weekday)`. The filled-in values are what's in the data set.

Comment: `res` has 76 observations, `dat` has 212. The blank tiles may just be missing data

Comment: @hrbrmstr can you please be more specific?  You think the problem is cause by dates not been sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who may face the same problem: Eventually I stumbled into package GoogleVis and calendarplot, which was exactly what I was looking for and can be implemented in a much easier way. 
In my case the code would be the following line:

```
gvisCalendar(res, datevar = "mydates", numvar = "value")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a date-arranged partial listing of `res`:

```
1     Feb         1       1
2     Feb         1       2
3     Feb         1       3
4     Feb         1       4
5     Feb         1       6
6     Feb         1       7
7     Feb         2       1
8     Feb         2       3
9     Feb         2       5
10    Mar         1       1
11    Mar         1       3
12    Mar         1       4
13    Mar         1       5
14    Mar         1       6
15    Mar         2       1
16    Mar         2       7
17    Mar         3       1
18    Mar         3       2
19    Mar         3       5
20    Mar         3       6
21    Mar         3       7
22    Mar         4       1
23    Mar         4       3
24    Mar         5       1
```

You don't have all of February (or March for that matter). What do you think it's going to plot?

If I just plot Feb & Mar:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(weekdayf, monthweek, fill=value)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="blue", na.value="black") + 
  geom_tile(colour = "black") + 
  facet_grid(monthf~.) +
  coord_equal() +
  xlab("Day") + ylab("Week of the month") +
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major=element_blank()) 

plot1 <- plot1 + scale_y_reverse() + coord_equal()
library(dplyr)
plot2 <- plot1 + geom_tile(data=filter(res, monthf %in% c("Feb", "Mar")), color="black")
plot2
```

It just plots what's there:

[image]

Comment: I understand your point and of course I know that my code is faulty.In case starting post is not clear enough: what I am trying to do is to use the first dataset to make a "calendar" and then use the primary dataset to fill wherever there is an observation.  I just also noticed that the monthweek assigned to values in res is wrong. Also I should really look more into dplyr :)

Comment: you seem to have accomplished that goal. the second dataset does not have observations for every day of every month.

Comment: First plot represents days of year 2015 as they are, ie. first day of February is Sunday, second one falsely moves that day to Monday. Due to tiredness I missed that weekday and monthweek in the res dataset are incorrect, a fact that if corrected should solve everything.